# Image in Tizen Mobile is not visible

Tags: image, mobile, shared, tizen

I am using `<Image Source="flower.png" />` code in Xamarin form in Visual Studio 2017 to show image in Tizen Mobile but it does not show up. I put image file in shared\res folder in Tizen project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the Image into '.TizenMobile' Project **'res'** directory (not in 'shared>res' only 'res' (root)). Then In Solution Explorer:Right click over 'res' folder and Add > Existing Item > png Image

In your ProjectCode (Portable) C# file:

```
 MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                        new Image {
                            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                            Source = ImageSource.FromFile("flower.png")
                        }
                }
            }
        };
```

Or you can even try the XAML.

[image]

Comment: It dose not work neither way. Just when the image source is URL.It works.

Comment: Now, worked on my machine. Edited the Answer, take a look.

Comment: Now ,It woks .Thanks for following up my issue.

Comment: The reason was res folder .It works with this code <Image Source="flower.png"></Image> too.